# OnResize vs OnSizeChanged

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the difference between these two events?  I can't think of any case where both wouldn't be called at the same time, and MSDN is less than enlightening.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Answer from Bob Powell [MVP] found on internet](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-1313419.php) (discussion goes further) :

> Internally, OnSizeChanged calls OnResize so they are pretty tightly linked.
>
> The OnResize method is responsible for invalidating the control if the ResizeRedraw style is set.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the `Resize`-Event is fired if the actual size of the form changes. The `SizeChanged`-Event fires if the value of the `Size`-Property is updated.